# Draw dashed linestring with real-size dashes in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3

I'd like to draw dashed linestring with real-size dashes, eg. each dash has to be long eg. 2 meters and space in between has to be eg. 1 meter.

How to achieve that?